# AWK - How move pattern match at the end of the file

Tags: awk

I've some files like this :

```
37M1|5|189|
37M1|5|190|
37M1|2|150|
ABC|AAA|BBBB
ABC1|AAB|BBBC
37M1|5|191|
37M1|3|111|
BBC1|AAB|BFBC
BBC2|AAA|BFBC
37M1|5|192|
```

I would like to move only lines begining with 37M1|5| at the end of the file

i.e this result

```
37M1|2|150|
ABC|AAA|BBBB
ABC1|AAB|BBBC
37M1|3|111|
BBC1|AAB|BFBC
BBC2|AAA|BFBC
37M1|5|192|
37M1|5|189|
37M1|5|190|
37M1|5|191|
```

Anyone know how to do it ? With AWK please :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
37M1|5|189|
37M1|5|190|
37M1|2|150|
ABC|AAA|BBBB
ABC1|AAB|BBBC
37M1|5|191|
37M1|3|111|
BBC1|AAB|BFBC
BBC2|AAA|BFBC
37M1|5|192|
```

then

```
awk 'index($0,"37M1|5|")==1{lines=lines "\n" $0;next}{print}END{print substr(lines,2)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
37M1|2|150|
ABC|AAA|BBBB
ABC1|AAB|BBBC
37M1|3|111|
BBC1|AAB|BFBC
BBC2|AAA|BFBC
37M1|5|189|
37M1|5|190|
37M1|5|191|
37M1|5|192|
```

Explanation: I use [`index`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to determine if current line starts with `37M1|5|`, this does not need counterbalancing `|` which has special meaning in regular expression. If yes I append newline and current line to `lines` and instruct GNU `AWK` to go `next` line so current line is not printed. All others lines are `print`ed as-is, whilst end of file is reached I `print` what is inside `lines` without 1st character (using `substr` function), which is newline.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*